# value is not a function AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to add a movieClip dynamically to another nested MC and wrote a small function with a fore loop and to test it I hard coded the route to my placeholder thus:

```
mcA.mcB.mcHolder.addChild(bm);
```

Worked a treat but I want the eventual route to be a little more dynamic. I want to get the event.currentTarget.name, drop it into and array ctArray so that I can reference it like this

```
ctArray[0].addChild(bm);
```

to test I populate ctArray[0] the same route as above and get: Error #1006: value is not a function. Which has confused me totally. Can anyone help explain this?

When I trace the array element it returns great

```
trace (ctArray[0]) ----  mcA.mcB.mcHolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you catch the `event.currentTarget`? I'm assuming `event.currentTarget` is your correct `MovieClip` for the following solution:

You wrote that you add `event.currentTarget.name` to the array. That's just the name of the `MovieClip` but not the movieclip itself. If you add `event.currentTarget` to the array it should work.